# Electrically charging objects with a battery?

Tags: electricity

hi this is a weird question but is it possible to positively or negatively (or both) charge an object with a battery? I need to do it with a battery for a project and i have seen designs but i really just need a simple explanation on how and why.

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to positively or negatively (or both) charge an object with a battery?

One possible way to do both in one shot is to make a capacitor out of two metal plates, by stacking them together with a piece of paper in between, and briefly connecting this capacitor to a battery.

As a result of such connection, the capacitor will be charged to the battery voltage: one plate will be charged positively, the other negatively. You can separate the plates and make some measurements, but you need to do it quickly (otherwise the charge will dissipate) and you need to wear rubber gloves (otherwise the charge will move to your body).